# Django Rest Framework: Elegant way to map URI version to view methods

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Django Rest framework seems to have nice way of mapping version to urls for classes using versioning_class  . I was wondering on how to achieve the same for stand alone methods. For example, currently I am doing the following

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def multi_disable(request,user_token,version):
  // Check the version number and execute the rest of the code 
  // Manually send appropriate response.
```

Is there a way, to use the version class which I already have in my code

```
class DataVersioning(URLPathVersioning):
    default_version = 'v1'
    allowed_versions = 'v1|v2'

@api_view(['POST'])
def multi_disable(request,user_token,version):
    versioning_class = DataVersioning
```

It ll be really easy if I only had to mention versioning_class in my standalone methods (these methods are not a part of any class) and have that taken care by DataVersioning.

Comment: As it is, `versioning_class` is a local variable with limited scope. Try setting it into the function namespace, e.g. `multi_disable.versioning_class = DataVersioning`, so it can be accessed from outside via `multi_disable.versioning_class`, as a class would allow. Mind you, in order for the variable to be set, the function must be called/executed, so I doubt it would work

Comment: You could try to use [URLPathVersioning](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#urlpathversioning). Should work.